# htaccess redirection 301 from subdomain to main domain subdirectory and proxy subdomain

Tags: apache, redirect, proxy, subdomain, subdirectory

I need help concerning a permanent redirection.

I have a wordpress blog on a server :
subdomain.toto.com (server 2)

I'd like to transfer it to :
www.toto.com/subdomain (server 1)
This new url will load the content from server 2

I've read through many posts that I'll need to use ProxyPass, ProxyPassReverse (in my main vhost) to load wordpress content.

It can load content from server 2 but the redirection is not applied for SEO.

I follow this topic (it describes the same problem) : https://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4567684.htm

But I'm finally lost.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You want when user types `http://www.toto.com/subdomain/something` (in browser address bar) to show him the content from `http://subdomain.toto.com/something` but keep his address bar unchanged?

Comment: The address bar must change with new url. My goal is to tell Google that all blogs articles are moved to http://www.toto.com/subdomain/ but I want to keep my server 2 with Wordpress.